# JSON validation against a schema (Java EE application)

Tags: json, validation

I have a use case where I need to validate JSON objects against a schema that can change real time..

Let me explain my requirements..

1. I persist JSON objects (MongoDB).
2. Before persisting I MUST validate the data type of some of the
   fields of JSON objects (mentioned in #1) against a schema.
3. I persist the schema in mongodb.
4. I always validate the JSON objects against the latest schema available in db. (so I dont think it matters much even if the schema can change in real time for me it is kinda static).

I am using a J2EE stack (Spring Framework).

Can anyone guide me here..?

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to use an external library https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator to do the work for you.  The one I proposed supports draft 4 of JSON Schema.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM DataPower appliance has JSON Schema validation support. This will allow you to offload validation to an appliance that is designed for it along with routing of data within te enterprise.

Comment: in case you are (or were) affiliated with IBM and/or any of its products, it's better to add a note